# Foreign key must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key for manyToMany

Tags: spring

here job has a set of employees, and employee have a set of jobs, but Spring give me this exception

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key
>   (FK1kec5bwba2rl0j8garlarwe3d:account [employee_id])) must have same
>   number of columns as the referenced primary key (employee
>   [job_id,employee_id])

this is my employee class :

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id ;
private String firstname ;
private String lastname ;
private String email ;
private String phone ;
private String address ;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
private Account account ;

public Account getAccount() {
    return account;
}
public void setAccount(Account account) {
    this.account = account;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "departement_id")
@JsonIgnore
private Departement departement ;
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "jobs", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "job_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Set<Job>jobs ;


....

}
```

and here is my job class :

```
@Entity
@Inheritance

public abstract class Job {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id ;

private String status ; // (pending or done)
private Date date ;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "employee", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "job_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Set<Employee> employee ;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "BusinnesPartner_id")
@JsonIgnore
private BusineesPartner busineesPartner ;








}
```

Please can you explain to me why I get this exception.

Answer (score 0):

@JoinTable annotation should be used in the owning entity side , in the other side you should not have @JoinTable , you need to have mappedBy to define the reverse relation since you are establishing a bidirectional relation is if the Job is the owning entity you need to modify Employee pojo

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="employee")
private Set<Job>jobs ;
```